# The feature Webalizer reporting cannot be disabled, as it is used by the following virtual servers

Tags: centos6, webalizer

I can't disable webalizer in Virtualmin because of this error:

```
Failed to save enabled features : The feature Webalizer reporting cannot be disabled, as it is used by the  :
```

How can I fix this? or How can I disable webalizer in `following virtual servers`?

Answer (score 1):

As Super Mario stated, you have to go into each individual virtual host in Virtualmin:

-> Edit Virtual Server -> Enabled Features -> Webalizer Reporting Enabled (untick) ->Save Virtual Server

Once that has been done you can then disable it globally.

Answer (score 0):

I should have disabled `Webalizer reporting` in all virtual servers first and then tried to disable it globally.